# PostgreSQL Server shuts down automatically after python start

Tags: postgresql, python

I am using the following code:

```
def start_postgresql_server():    
    status = subprocess.run(["pg_ctl", "-D", fr"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/14/data", "status"],
                            capture_output=True, text=True)
    if "server is running" in status.stdout:
        print("PostgreSQL server is already running.")
    else:
        subprocess.run(["pg_ctl", "-D", fr"C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/{version}/data", "start"], check=True)
```

But the server shuts down on its own as you can see in the log:

```
2023-03-17 23:42:49.632 CDT [22452] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.5, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
2023-03-17 23:42:49.633 CDT [22452] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-03-17 23:42:49.633 CDT [22452] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-03-17 23:42:49.670 CDT [20072] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-03-17 23:42:24 CDT
2023-03-17 23:42:49.697 CDT [22452] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-03-17 23:43:18.138 CDT [22452] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2023-03-17 23:43:18.138 CDT [22648] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2023-03-17 23:43:18.138 CDT [7524] ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
2023-03-17 23:43:18.139 CDT [22452] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2023-03-17 23:43:18.140 CDT [22452] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 22648) exited with exit code 1
2023-03-17 23:43:18.162 CDT [19880] LOG:  shutting down
2023-03-17 23:43:18.178 CDT [22452] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

The server should be up and running on its own but it keeps shutting down so thought about writing the python script to check the status of server.

Edit:

My PostgreSql server has IP address of 192.168.0.197 which is local IP. So, not likely that it has been hacked.

Is there any diagnostics that I can run to trace the application which is forcing it's shutdown. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: "*received fast shutdown request*" - something from the outside is sending a shutdown request. This is not initiated by Postgres itself

Comment: So apparently whatever was shutting it down before is still shutting it down now.  Fix the real problem, rather than plastering ineffective Band-Aids over it.  Likely you've been hacked, as shutting down the server which let them is has become a common thing among the crypto-miners.

Comment: @jjanes please see my Edit.

Comment: I would start with turning on log_connections and log_disconnections.  They won't directly tell you who is commanding the shutdown, but it a pretty fair bet that is coming from someone who had recently connected or attempted to connect.